# How to get my tweets from my personal Twitter account appear in my company's Twitter account

Tags: twitter

I have set up both a personal Twitter account and a corporate Twitter account. I have my corporate Twitter account following my personal account. The idea is that I want everything I tweet to be shown on the "home" page of the corporate Twitter account.

I am using various platforms/applications (e.g., inkedIn, Posterous, etc.) to send tweets under my personal Twitter account. However, to my dismay, all of the tweets I have sent from another application, are not being shown on my followers page (i.e., my corporate Twitter account).

Is there any special setup that I have to do, so that when I tweet via another app (under my personal account), those tweets are picked up by people following me on Twitter (including my corporate account)?

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't have those apps posting to the Corporate Account? I mean, you want everything to go there anyway; I'm not clear on the purpose of having two accounts.

Answer (score 2):

One method would be to automatically retweet everything by the one account. A quick web search shows that there are multiple ways of accomplishing this. One way is using Yahoo! Pipes. (An example of how to do that: http://hubpages.com/hub/How-to-automatically-retweet-on-Twitter-using-Yahoo-Pipes-and-Twitterfeed-auto-RT-explained)

Comment: I've never heard of yahoo pipes. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You would have to Re-Tweet them.  Just because your corporate account is following your personal account, doesn't mean anyone else will see your personal tweets.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recipe from IFTTT.

There is a rule you can setup where anything that is being tweeted by a profile can be retweeted by your own profile and vice-versa.

This is what I would use.